# numprint makes \rho_{ij} not work

Tags: math-mode, packages, numprint

I didn't find a good title to this subject. Maybe someone can improve it?

I want to create this table:

[image]

The problem is that I need the package `numprint`.

But then the table looks like this 
[image]

You see that the `\rho_{ij}` is not printed how it should be anymore.

Can someone help me here? 
The code I used is:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{numprint}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{n{1}{0}n{1}{1}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}}
RP[\%]  &             & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\Delta_{ij}$}                            \\ \cline{3-8}
$\sigma_i=\sigma_j$ & $\rho_{ij}$ & 0.0\%  & 0.2\%  & 0.4\%   & 0.6\%   & 0.8\%   & 1.0\%   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `$\rho_{{ij}}$`

Comment: Why should the first two columns be `n`? Just declare them as `l`.

Answer (score 4):

The first two columns don't hold numeric values, so they should simply be declared as `l`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}

\begin{tabular}{lln{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}}
RP[\%]  &             & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\Delta_{ij}$}                            \\ \cline{3-8}
$\sigma_i=\sigma_j$ & $\rho_{ij}$ & 0.0\%  & 0.2\%  & 0.4\%   & 0.6\%   & 0.8\%   & 1.0\%   \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with `siunitx` (and `booktabs` for aesthetics), where all the % signs are made implicit in the header.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}

\begin{tabular}{ll *{6}{S[table-format=1.1]}}
\toprule
RP (\%)  &             & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\Delta_{ij}$ (\%)} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){3-8}
$\sigma_i=\sigma_j$ & $\rho_{ij}$ & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 1.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, subscripts have to be grouped again if used in table columns when `numprint` is applied. The same error would occur for `\sigma_{ik}` etc. The `\Delta_{ij}` is correct since the table columns are grouped in a centered multicolumn, not using `n` type.

Both `\sigma` and `\rho` are in columns not using numbers, i.e. `n` type isn't needed there.

If this should be changed later on, `\multicolumn{c}{$\sigma_{i}$}` could be used to switch back to another column type.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{numprint}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{n{1}{0}n{1}{1}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}n{1}{2}}
RP[\%]  &             & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\Delta_{ij}$}                            \\ \cline{3-8}
$\sigma_i=\sigma_{j}$ & $\rho_{{ij}}$ & 0.0\%  & 0.2\%  & 0.4\%   & 0.6\%   & 0.8\%   & 1.0\%   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]